# "Dumb" text completion in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way to get "dumb" word completion in Eclipse, similar to ctrl+p in Vim?

For example, I often write a function call:

```
x = getMeAnXPlease();
```

Then go in to write the definition:

```
function getMe...
```

At which point, in Vim, I hit ctrl+p, which will complete the 'getMe' to 'getMeAnXPlease'.

Is there something similar for Eclipse?

**Edit**: I know that ctrl+space does a context-sensitive completion and ctrl-1 is the magic "fix this line" key... But there are situations where I just want context-insensitive completion... Which seems to be provided by the 'Word Completion' command.

**Edit**: Next question: is it possible to do context-insensitive line-completion (similar to c-x c-l in Vim)?  That is, complete the current line with a similar line:

```
doSomeThing(1, 2, 3, 4);
doSome <c-x c-l> -- inserts the rest of the 'doSomeThing(1, 2, 3, 4);' line
```

Comment: BTW, this is usually called "hippie completion" - http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11668

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah ha! Found it.

There is a 'word completion' feature which defaults to 'ctrl-.'.

Comment: FYI, word completion defaults to 'Alt+/' here on my german Windows XP. 'Ctrl+.' is used to navigate to the next problem marker.
To see all commands type 'Ctrl+Shift+L'...
'Ctrl+3' is really nice as well...

Comment: Yea, I came across ctrl+3 by accident... It's good stuff.
Also, ctrl-. may be strange for me because I'm on a mac :P

Answer (score 5):

Write x = getMeAnXPlease();

Wait a second until compiler understands there's no such method.

Hit Ctrl-1 and Enter - it will create full method body automatically.

Comment: +1 This is actually the easiest way of doing something as simple as the question entails.

Comment: Also, for this to work you'd have to have the cursor on the method, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I'd love to, but I'm working in FlexBuilder which lacks any reasonable quick-fixing :'(

Answer (score 3):

There is actually, it's called templates and there are a multitude of them, a lot more advanced than simple word completion. Look at:

Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Editor --> Templates

for a list of the current templates and the possibility to add more. You would then use Ctrl + Space for the completion to pop up. If you write "sysout" and press Ctrl + Space, for example, you get "System.out.Println([cursor here]);".

I wrote a sample one myself for adding Before functions to JUnit test cases:

`@${testType:newType(org.junit.Before)}
public final void setUp() throws Exception {
    ${cursor} 
}`

Which would be triggered by typing "before" and Ctrl + Space.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+Space for completion

Ctrl+1 (or Cmd+1) for hints on the code snippet you are working on (like automatically create the missing method, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

A little more detail on Quick Fix (Ctrl+1 or Cmd+1).  Instead of going somewhere to start defining the new method, you can simply invoke Quick Fix from the place where you call the nonexistent method.  It will create a new empty function with the correct name and leave your cursor in position to fill it in.